# how to make flask pagination keep the query condition

Tags: flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

here is my view function:

```
def get_user_info():
    form = UserInfoForm()
    query = UserInfo.query
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        query = query.filter_by(sex=form.sex.data)
    flag = False
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = query.paginate(page=page, per_page=10, error_out=False)
    return render_template("user_info.html", form=form,data=pagination.items, pagination=pagination)
```

and here is part of my html:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{{url_for('.get_user_info')}}", method="post">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.sex.label }}:
        {{ form.sex(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my pagination macro:

```
{% macro pagination_widget(pagination, endpoint) %}
{% if pagination.total != 0 %}
<ul class="pagination">
    <li{% if pagination.page == 1 %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{% if pagination.page != 1 %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=1, **kwargs) }}
{% else %}#{% endif %}">&laquo;&laquo;</a>
</li>
<li{% if not pagination.has_prev %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
<a href="{% if pagination.has_prev %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.page - 1, **kwargs) }}
{% else %}#{% endif %}">&laquo;</a>
</li>
{% for p in pagination.iter_pages() %}
{% if p %}
    <li {% if p == pagination.page %} class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page = p, **kwargs) }}">{{ p }}</a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<li{% if not pagination.has_next %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{% if pagination.has_next %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.page+1, **kwargs) }}
    {% else %}#{% endif %}">&raquo;</a>
</li>
<li{% if pagination.page == pagination.pages %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
<a href="{% if pagination.page != pagination.pages %}{{ url_for(endpoint, page=pagination.pages, **kwargs) }}
{% else %}#{% endif %}">&raquo;&raquo;</a>
</li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I use a selectfiled sex in my page, when I select male in my page, I get the paginate object and my first page user is all male.But when I click next page, the results will have both male and female, I just want it like the first page, it has only male user info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem today.
There are *args, and **kwargs for any macro, so I can pass parameters of query condition to it and in my view functions use request.args.get() to obtain parameters and set it to form.